# jquery selectmenu loading time, is Internet Explorer too fast?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

i thought of using jquery ui selectmenus instead to improve the standard ones a bit. Everything works except in the internet explorer i have the following problem:

I have a selectmenu in the header and in explorer you can see for a milisecond the standard selectmenu before the jquery one is shown up. This flashing is very annoying because it happens every time.

Is there maybe any workaround i can prevent the internet explorer from showing the original selectmenu before the jquery one is loaded?

Thank you for any help

Ruven

Comment: Ha Ha Ha Ha.....if there was one thing that IE will never EVER be accused of, it's being too fast.

Comment: i was thinking the exact same thing

Comment: yeah ok but this only happens in IE not in any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the SELECT with css:

```
display:none;
```

After you can show it with JQuery using the method show()

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: thx for the fast answer. you mean setting a timeout and then show the selectmenu? Yeah i thought of it, but the display: none is being ignored because jquery.selectmenu seems to overwrite it.

Comment: No, you can set the style for default to display:none. Then after the data was loaded you call to method show. Also you can use a StyleSheet for this kinf of componentes and do it for all.

Comment: sorry for the answer but what do you mean "style for default"? select `{ display: none; }`? Does not work.

Comment: You must use something like input[type="text"] {display:none;}. But I think that a class would be better.

Comment: hm yes i had a mistake in my code. this works but is only a workaround. Not really a good solution. But it seems so, that tere ist no other option?